# Code duplication for updating 2 fields with the DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, refactoring

I have 1 long running process running against an entity for which I update `StartTime and EndTime` in a database table and than I have 1 seperate endpoint which get display `StartTime,EndTime` and total time taken by the entity to process.

Below are the 2 methods  :

```
 public class DbModule
        {
            private readonly string _connectionString;
            public DbModule() { }

            public DbModule(string connectionString)
            {
                _connectionString = connectionString;
            }

     public void UpdateRegionStartTime(int moduleId,int regionId)
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    string query = "Update Module_Region_Mapping set [StartDateTime]=@StartDateTime where ModuleId=@ModuleId and RegionId=@RegionId";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModuleId", moduleId);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegionId", regionId);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDateTime", DateTime.Now);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            public void UpdateRegionEndTime(int moduleId,int regionId)
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    string query = "Update Module_Region_Mapping set [EndDateTime]=@EndDateTime where                 ModuleId=@ModuleId and RegionId=@RegionId";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModuleId", moduleId);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegionId", regionId);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDateTime", DateTime.Now);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
      }

public class MyProcessor
{
   public void Process(int moduleId,int regionId)
   {
      var dbModule = new DbModule("connection string");
      try
      {
         dbModule.UpdateRegionStartTime(100, 101);
         LongRunningProcess();
         dbModule.UpdateRegionEndTime(100,101);
      }
      catch(){}
    }
}
```

But I feel like a code duplication as it is just 2 fields that is getting updated with the same function(`DateTime.Now`).

So having seperate method like this(`UpdateRegionStartTime` and `UpdateRegionEndTime`) make sense as it improves readability though at the cost of code duplication or it can better be refactored to something which reduces code duplication but still keeps readibility?

Comment: Two separate methods is clear, simple and easy to understand. Leave it how you have it. _Note you can remove the `connection.Close();` - it doesn't do anything that your `using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))` doesn't already achieve for you._ You may also want to consider reading up on Dapper or PetaPoco to avoid the boilerplate `SqlCommand` and parameter code.

Comment: I would use a stored procedure (parameterized query) instead of hard coding sql statements and you could make one stored procedure that takes in both the start time, endtime and identity so that you can do the update in one call to sql, just my opinion. So, store your starttime as a variable, then grab your end time after said long running process, and then pass both starttime, and endtime and identity to stored procedure, one update call and you are done.

Comment: @mjwills Sometimes code readability at the expense of code duplication is worth it?

Comment: The amount of code duplication here is quite minimal. If you switched to Dapper or PetaPoco and kept the rest of your structure the same you'd get the conciseness benefits but still keep the simplicity and clarity of your existing code. That is what I would recommend. I mean, sure you could have a single method that took an enum / boolean parameter and ran different SQL based on the parameter. That would reduce duplication, but then the code is much harder to read and reason about. `UpdateRegionEndTime` on the other hand is **super** clear. I can tell **exactly** what it does.

Comment: @mjwills This is relatively very very small class library which have 9-10 function dealing with database hence orm(dapper) would be overhead for such a small library.This is the reason I havent used any orm.What do you think?

Comment: I think I'd use Dapper. I would never, unless really necessary, be newing up `SqlCommand`s manually. :)

Comment: Yes - that is why I keep saying I'd keep your existing solution. Clarity is critical. Your code is clear. _Again, I'd use Dapper or remove the connection closing - but they are minor concerns._

Answer (score 1):

If your process is stable, and if your requirements allow it, you could do the update of both start and end-time in 1 method.

If this is not an option, than your current 2 method setup is fine. It separates the actual action/behavior in a clear descriptive way, which is actually a good thing, even better than the "do not repeat yourself" paradigm.

Nevertheless; an example:

```
var startTime = DateTime.Now;
LongRunningProcess();
var endTime = DateTime.Now; //used for clarity.
dbModule.UpdateStats(100,101,startTime,endTime);
```

Comment: Or you can make one generic method which takes in the name of a stored procedure and a list of parameters, then all subsequent methods can just pass what they need to the generic method so not only do you keep descriptive methods, but also follow the don't repeat yourself.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest _not_ using stored procs for simple SQL like this.

Comment: @RyanWilson Could you show me how that generic method would look so that I could learn something out of it please :)

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow That would be a new question and not relevant to this post, if you want a possible solution as you requested, either post a new question and send me a link to it, or we can move to chat and I can share some code samples which I have written.